# STM32F407 powering via tlink but not USB and ST-LINK not working

Tags: stm32, bootloader, st-link, stm32f407

Some background first. I have a custom STM32 board using a F407 MCU. The board takes 12 V and regulates to 5V then to 3.3V to feed the processor. That feed is directly connected to a SWD header using only 3.3V, GND, SDIO, SDCLK and Boot0.

The problem is if I put Boot0 to 3.3V and power the system from the USB, the boot-loader will not come up, and if I connect only the GND and the 3.3V from the ST-LINK to the same 3.3V onboard, the boot-loader comes up then I can remove the ST-LINK power.

ST-LINK is at 3.27V and the onboard regulator is at 3.24V which I think is acceptable, any ideas?

Also when I connect the SWDIO and SDCLK, the ST-LINK still cannot see the processor. I have checked the traces and the pins are connected. --- Fixed

Update #1: The problem with the SWDIO and SCLK was fixed as the SWDIO pin was permanently at 3.3v (defective Chip). The chip was replaced the first problem still remains.

Comment: I think you can configure the ST-Link to only sense voltage on the 3.3V line and not supply it; you should do that. I'm not sure if it's possible to use the ST-Link to program via the bootloader, and that's what you're doing? ..But the normal way to program (not using the bootloader) requires the nRST line.

Comment: ST-Link won't give 3.3V out so it can't power anything on board. It's the board that gives a 3.3V IO voltage reference to ST-Link. Well, unless you have an unspecified clone so those can and will do any unspecified things instead of the genuine one.

Comment: The ST-LINK can indeed power the chip and does provide 3.3V I have been programming it in this way since I first got into STM32's without any issues.

Comment: @dj_nexxus In that case, maybe you want to disclose which version of ST-Link you mean, and is it genuine device from ST or an unofficial clone?

Comment: Justme - It's a clone, one of the cheap Chinese versions, but it has an Atmega 328 in it using ST-LINK utility v3.9 I am using the 5V from the USB connector to feed a 3.3v regulator just cant figure out why it will not go into the bootloader while under that power